# What is a Domain in Oracle (related to Constraint)?

Tags: sql, oracle, dns, constraints, integrity

What is a Domain in Oracle? I didn't really find something useful on the internet.

I have a question which i have to answer: "What is the difference between Constraints and Domains in Oracle?"

I understand Constraints, but i have no idea about "Domains" in Oracle.

Thanks for help!

Comment: A domain is a data type, with optional check constraints.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know and with some search , oracle doesnt support domain constraint

Anyway this [pdf](http://cs.gmu.edu/~jessica/cs450_s12/cs450_SQL3.pdf) contain a lot of information about domain constraint , Ill past some here

```
                Using Domain Constraints
 A domain can be used instead of one of the base
types in a CREATE TABLE statement

– Comparisons between two domains are made in terms of
the underlying base types

 e.g. comparing an age with an account number domain simply
compares two integers
 The SQL:1999 standard introduced syntax for distinct
types
– Types are distinct so that values of different types cannot
be compared
```

**Not supported by Oracle

   – Create a table that holds the domain values instead, and
    reference this table**